# delete words after custom word in Zapier Run Javascript

Tags: javascript, zapier

I create a zap (Wordpress to Chatfuel).
I want delete part of Wordpress post after a word.
I need a java code to insert to Zapier Run Javascript.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As good of an answer as is the question.

```
var output = input.split('WORD')[0]+'WORD';

console.log(output);
```